# Visualforce page: Table does not add a page break on rowspanned cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, visualforce, page-break

I'm having the same issue related this question: [table rowspan page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312077/table-rowspan-page-break/75188225?noredirect=1#comment132680615_75188225)

In my Visualforce page, my html table has a column with a custom rowspan (depending on the amount of rowspanned rows) and I'm having a style issue (please see the issue in the green square):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ehNl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJscf.png)

I'm using a tr with style as page-break-before: auto and a dynamic rowspan (depending on business logic)

I tried with the apge-break-inside in the rowspanned tr, but without result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding inner tables in the rows inside the main table instead of using rowspan property in the 'tr' and not using page breaks:

```
 <table class="general">
    <thead style="display: table-header-group; valign: top">
    .
    .
    .
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!VALUE}" var="VAR">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!VALUE}" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!VALUE}" var="VAR">
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!value}" />
                    </td>
             </tr>
             </apex:repeat>
             </table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```